# jQuery StopPropagation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to close the div if someone clicked outside that div. I have the below code:

```
   $('body').click(function(e) {
        $('div.test').slideUp('slow');
    });
    $('div.test').live('click',function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

But the issue is that when someone click inside the div, the div itself is closing. I want to prevent that. After debugging I found a weird stuff the debugger is hitting the $(body).click first instead of $(div.test), May I know the reason for this? Can you help me in fixing the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your use of [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live).

`live` is a way of saying "bind a handler to the root element and capture any events that originated on an element matching a selector".  It's a short form of [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate).  This is possible because of "bubbling": events on elements are triggered on the element's ancestors as well.

If you do not specify otherwise, `live` binds the event handler to the `document`.  The event handler on the `body` will be triggered first since the event won't have bubbled up to the `document` handler, where the [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) is.

The easiest solution would be to change `live` to `click`:

```
$('div.test').click(function(e) {
```

If you need to use `live`, introduce a container element, and handle the event there. I'll use `delegate` as I prefer its syntax, but you could use `live` if you preferred:

```
$('#container').delegate('div.test', 'click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The event is handled on `#container` and propagation is stopped, so the event never reaches the `body`'s event handler.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you handle the body click with `live()` too?

I believe the live click handler doesn't propagate the event in the same way as a standard click. See [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: Perfect! It worked with $('body').live('click', function(e) {
                .......            });  Thanks for the solution. But I am curious to know how did it work? Why it worked now and why it was not working before ? Why did the $('div.test').live('click' fire before in this case?

Comment: See what lonesomeday said, but I leave the choice of which answer to accept to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem arises because you are setting a click handler to `<body>`

I tried the same thing with `<p>` instead of `<body>` and it seems to work fine.

Here's a relevant fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/seNXV/7/

Answer (score 0):

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) does not stop propagation. Says do in the jQuery docs.

You need to use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)